# Warning: App must target Android 13 (API level 33) or higher. It does

Tags: android, google-play-console

I received the following warning from Google Play Console that our app does not meet the minimum target API level. However, it does and below is the code for it:

```
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        //TODO: Keep an eye on targetSdkVersion number, as it has to be within one year of major android release.
        applicationId "com.com"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

This is the image showing the warning:
[image]

Then, when I click on the affect app bundles, they are really old ones from over 2 years ago:
[image]

Should I just delete these older bundles or do I need to do something else? I am worried because it says we will not be able to update the app unless we meet the requirements (which the newest code does).

**UPDATE:** After first updating each track (even paused ones) with a compliant app bundle according to the answers below, sending them for review, and then publishing those changes (again even if the track is inactive), my warning of not being able to update the app persisted. So I reached out to Google directly and received the following message about the warning. I guess we will see what happens the next time I try to update the app

*"As per checking, this warning is with regards to Google Play's target API level requirement which only warns the developers about the risk of not releasing a compliant app version. In this case, you may ignore this warning and you can rest assured that you will still be able to release an app update.
I hope this helps. Please let me know if you have any other questions about the Play Console and we'll be happy to help."*

**Update of Update:** After publishing and clicking on the message in the Inbox, a new message appeared saying violation was resolved (as mentioned below).

Comment: Just got a very similar warning in email, I'm in the very same situation. Let's pray that it is Google bug otherwise we are fkd.

Comment: I had a similar case. You should check are there released old bundles to Open Testing, Closed testing, Internal testing and deactivate them or upload the latest bundles to these tracks

Comment: @DmitriChernysh I am guessing it something to what you are saying, but I am not seeing an obvious way to deactivate the specific bundles causing the error. How do you do this?

Comment: @DmitriChernysh I am wondering if you just 'Pause Track' to stop this from happening?

Comment: Probably Pause will not help. There should be a button "Deactive". is there? Sorry my tracks are already inactive, not able to check. But I see Pause button as well for inactive tracks

Comment: Found this Step 5, Google says to use Pause button =)  https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9845334?hl=en-GB&visit_id=638279756931799681-520338942&rd=1

Comment: I am having same issue, updated all my apps to targetsdk 33, also updated my old internal testing bundles to 33. It is still showing warning message

Comment: Same experience here. I have found old packages in open testing and also replaced them with current ones, paused the testing tracks but the warning is still there. Very unnerving to see that.

Comment: Update: after I've fixed all "affected app bundles" that button has now disappeared but the threatening text "You won't be..." remains. Not good.

Comment: @BPorr same for me, the "affected app bundles" button is gone, but the warning is still there

Comment: I face the same issue. It's indeed amusing how big corporations resort to manipulative messaging to influence our actions. They wield tremendous power over us. Whoever crafts these messages is undeniably cunning and shrewd. But, for the time being, it is what it is. Eventually, everyone gets a taste of their own medicine.

Comment: Same issue as @BPorr - Internal testing track updated to support API 33+ - but the 'View affected app bundle' button is gone, with the status of You won't be able to release app updates (10 days away) remaining. I do not know how to resolve this.

Comment: Same. I updated all of the tracks (even paused ones) and the warning persists. I hope once it goes through review and published it will go away. It is stupid that clearly dead tracks (even paused ones) need to be 'updated'. Terrible rollout as usual by Google.

Comment: Same here. I don't even have the "affected app bundles" but under the How to fix it section, it says "Once you've done this, we'll send you an Inbox message to confirm that your app update was successful, and that your app is no longer affected."

Comment: Any resolution for this issue?

Comment: After I fixed problem version "View affected app bundle" button stopped showing. But warning message is still appear in Policy section

Comment: classic google fail.  my app targeted 33 since it was released.

Comment: why everybody is trying to solve artificial problem created by E-corp instead of fighting for old android users' rights?

Comment: Classic Googlers - once again, for gazilionth time, a bug in their console and a false warning. When will they finally learn?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I was faced with this warning for a similar reason - I had a package with an old *target api version* in internal testing paused.

***The solution to this problem is to update all active application packages released in production or testing.***

To see a list of all app bundles that need to be updated, you should go to:

***Inbox > Click your affected warning message > View details > View app bundles*** - This will list all app bundles and where they are released - Production or testing.

Also, you can check them by going to the `App Bundle Explorer` and checking all versions with `Release status` is `Active` for matching target sdk
In my case, it was paused version `1.0.0` with `target sdk 31` for internal testing:
[image: App Bundle Explorer]

You need to go to the partition where the active version with target sdk < 33 is located and do the following:
***Add new release > Add from library > Set checkbox on your app bundle with target sdk 33 or more > Add to release > Next > Save and publish***

Then if you go back to ***Inbox > Click your warning message > View details*** you will no longer see the `View affected app bundles` button, and you will have the following notification:

[image: Notification]

Thus, after completing all the actions, all your active releases will comply with the rules

**UPD:**

After completing all the above steps and successfully completing the review, the warning message will disappear and you will receive the following message in your `Inbox`:

[image: Message]

Comment: I went through and did this to all affected tracks, even though they were paused (which didn't do anything to the warning). I hoping once it goes through review and is published, it will all go away. Terrible messaging by Google.

Comment: I don't think you should worry about this since you've already updated all the affected app bundles to the correct target sdk . If this is a production released version, then it should pass the review without any problems. However, if you're still worried, in ***Inbox > Warning message > View details*** you can request more time until `Nov 1, 2023` to update your app by clicking the `Request more time` button. But I think that first you need to wait for the result of the review, and if the review is not completed closer to `Aug 31, 2023` then request more time.

Comment: `You need to go to the partition where the active version with target sdk < 33 is located ` -> where is that?

Comment: @Michał, this is in the `App Bundle Explorer` and means you have to view the details of each item with the status *Active*, and find those whose `target sdk < 33` *(shown in the first screenshot)*. The best option is to look at all the inconsistencies in your warning message.

Comment: After I fixed problem version "View affected app bundle" button stopped showing. But warning message is still appear in Policy section

Comment: @VictorSklyarov even after review and publishing the changes to the paused tracks, the warning still shows. Very frustrating.

Comment: @DennisAshford, I have updated the answer, the warning message is gone after review.

Comment: @VictorSklyarov correct. It must have taken a bit of time, but I finally received the same message also.

Comment: @DennisAshford, if you think this answer can help others with a similar problem, you can mark it as accepted.

Comment: My issue is that the instructions say you can create an internal release to update the targetSdkVersion. I can't even do that so I'm stuck... When I try to create internal test, it says I can't until I resolve the issue. But the issue is telling me to create an internal test to release...so...what do you want me to do google?

Comment: @ShrimpCrackers no, you don't need to create an internal test to solve this problem. I cited my case when the reason for me was that I still had a package with an old version of the target sdk in internal testing. In your case, this could be internal testing, closed testing, open testing, or even a production version. You just need to identify the app bundles that received warnings and update them to the required target sdk, even if those app bundles are in testing that has been paused.

Answer (score 6):

This is what worked for me, It appears the Play Console bot assumes you haven't taken any action to resolve the policy breach if you don't click on the message sent to Inbox.

**Try 1**

To fix this, go to the `Dashboard`, click `Inbox`, and open the message that contains the warning about the **target Android 13 (API level 33) or higher**.

**Try 2**

Incase that dose not work for you even when it should. Click on `Dashboard` you will notice an error telling you about the target policy at the very top, click on that it will then take to to the `Policy status`

**Try 3**

Click on the `App bundle explorer` and make sure only your production bundle is active and the rest are inactive. Also check `Your internal, closed and open testing` and if there are active bundles make sure pause all of them.

Do this and you will receive a message in your inbox saying **A recent policy warning about your app has been addressed.**

Comment: I had published a compliant app (only one active in production) on Aug 19, and was still seeing this warning until today when I followed "Try 1" above. That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, yesterday it was solved.

My problem was that I had a very old version of my app as an active Track in 'Open Testing' and 'Closed Testing'.

My latest version was in 'Internal Testing' as well, so the solution was to promote this version to 'Closed Testing' and publishing it and wait for a short while, and then when it was available in 'Closed Testing' I promoted it again to 'Open Testing' and publishing it and wait for a while again until it was available in 'Open Test'.

By doing this the old version of my app was removed from both the Closed and Open Testing sections and was replaced with the new version (similar to production version).

After doing this the button was disappeared that says 'check Affected bundles' but the alert message was still there showing; and then after 2 hours approximately I received the message from Google that everything is OK now and I will be able to send updates in the future normally.

The production app version was not modified and no update was sent to users.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a delay on Google Play to update the status of each app. I simply updated some of my apps and did nothing else. Today the WARNING MESSAGE is gone for those apps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, this is because you [might have older versions of your app that are in one of the internal test tracks](https://multiverseapp.com/blog/how-to-target-android-13-api-level-33/).

[image]

You will have to update these older test tracks as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check in AndroidManifest.xml "<application" tag
if tools:targetApi is 33

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you try to update after **31 Aug 2023**, you have to **Request Additional time for update!** check ***Inbox > Click your affected warning message > View details*** then in below you'll see **request time for update** then send request. Now turn back your update dashboard and now your app updatable.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was an old version under 'internal testing', after upload a new version with sdk on corretly version, in a few hours the message disappeared

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I updated the SDK version from `31` to `33` in `build.gradle`.

```
compileSdkVersion = 33
targetSdkVersion = 33
```

Then compile a new bundle, using it to create releases listed in the  `View affected app bundle` (including testing and production) to deactivate the old outdated bundle.

The warning is no longer presented afterward.