# Google Play Console - App must target Android 13 (API level 33) or higher

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have application on google play and I received message that I must update api to support android 13 or higher, because my application targets android 10.[image]

This is very weird, because my application targets level 33 already (as shown on picture below).

[image]

In build.gradle I set (i believe correctly)

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    buildToolsVersion '32.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 33
    }
```

Do I set build.gradle correctly to target api level 33+? Does someone experience the same warning from google ?

Comment: click on "view affected app bundles" and you will see where exactly is the problem. In my case it was some old test bundles in alpha channel...

Comment: Thank you, you are right. Omg, it is two years old closed testing version. Lol, what can I do with this?

Comment: I believe it's not an issue, so I let it be..

Comment: I am not sure...they have everything automatic, if I received this message then my app fell into some case and i will have surely problems.

Comment: Don't worry, there will be no issues. Only people who don't update their app bundles to at least version 33 won't be able to upload those bundles. It's not your case...

Comment: Try this and thank me you will later
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76945457/16231514

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning: App must target Android 13 (API level 33) or higher. It does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76931031/warning-app-must-target-android-13-api-level-33-or-higher-it-does)

Answer (score 0):

Click "View affected app bundles" to see the problematic bundle. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76939517/22131563

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).