# App must target Android 13 (API level 33) or higher Fix by Aug 31 (11 days away)

Tags: android

I have received an email from Google Play

App must target Android 13 (API level 33) or higher
Fix by Aug 31 (11 days away)
Warning sent Aug 11, 2023

My app already targets API level 33. Why has this email been sent to me?

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.codeplayon.com.parmitmalik.femaleworkout"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 11
        versionName '1.2.0'
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't flag as a duplicate because it doesn't have an answer yet, but take a look at the comments on https://stackoverflow.com/q/76931031/2422776 - seems like the same issue.

Comment: Try this and thank me you will later
[Click to see answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76945457/16231514)