# App must target Android 13 (API level 33) or higher on Google Play Console

Tags: android

I received this notice on Google Play Console even though my app has target skd 33
[image]

I looked under **Reviewed app bundle** and it seems like the problem comes from some old internal/closed testing bundles. I want to pause them but the **Pause track** button on the right is disabled. Is there a way to edit it or delete? Or can i simply ignore that message?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning: App must target Android 13 (API level 33) or higher. It does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76931031/warning-app-must-target-android-13-api-level-33-or-higher-it-does)

Comment: Also this issue is a dealbreaker for Google. So there will be no subsequent app visibility in the playstore if the issue is not resolved.