App must target Android 14 (API level 34) or higher is showing even after update to API level 34
I updated the target API level (targetsdkversion) of the project from 33 to 34. The build process was successful.My build was successful then upload the app bundle.
Warning Message Image
The error message is still showing after updates in inbox:

Error Message in inbox:

Another thing I found there is a bundle which was my first build showing Active,is it creating problem?:


Can you share your android/app/build.gradle and android/settings.gradle?

@NipulRathod Yes
https://gist.github.com/SambasBoyyyy/ee6e589508d38fe5e770bfbc66d5d84d

I wouldn't label your question a duplicate, but check out this similar question/answer when this happened with api 33. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76931031/warning-app-must-target-android-13-api-level-33-or-higher-it-does?rq=1

First I have updated my to
targetSdkVersion 34
compileSdkVersion 34
then still got the same error then i checked my (open testing,closed,and internal testing ) track .Then I discovered a app bundle with targetsdk 33 in Internal testing , I replaced it with latest one then after 24 hours I got a Inbox message and it solved .Thanks

thank you! Just a quick remark for others: in my case the policy warning wasn't removed right after the release. I had to wait for ~7 hours until the policy warning was removed and I received the following message in the Google Play Console: "A recent policy violation in your app has been addressed"

Thank you very much. This helped me solve my problem.

Thank you, I changed mine to 35 for both

I got the same warning which buzzled me because I too have set targetSdk to 34, but after viewing the details of the warning and clicking view app bundles apparently it was the internal testing track that was affected not the production track, the latest release in there targeted api 33 !!
So I just created a new release in the internal testing track using add from library

You need to update the compileSdkVersion to 34 and the targetSdkVersion to 34 like this:
In your android/app/build.gradle
targetSdkVersion 34

compileSdkVersion 34


But i have already updated it and upload it this is my build.gradle
(http://gist.github.com/SambasBoyyyy/ee6e589508d38fe5e770bfbc66d5d84d)

First I have updated my targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion to:
targetSdkVersion: 34
compileSdkVersion: 34
But my issue was not solved then I've updated my minSdkVersion to 34 and now it is solved

Keep in mind that setting your minSdkVersion to 34 currently excludes a vast amount of devices for your app: https://apilevels.com/

please check any testing track is live in release  (open testing,closed,and internal testing )

I did it like this and it worked;
Open your android/app/build.gradle and change your targetSdkVersion 34 compileSdkVersion 34:

And go to this path open flutter.gradle file:

Change your targetSdkVersion = 34 and compileSdkVersion = 34


with flutter update local.properties file like below
sdk.dir=/Users/macbook/Library/Android/sdk
flutter.sdk=/Users/macbook/development/flutter
flutter.buildMode=release
flutter.versionName=1.0.8
flutter.versionCode=49
flutter.compileSdkVersion = 34
flutter.targetSdkVersion = 34


First update the
android/build.gradle
compileSdkVersion = 34
targetSdkVersion = 34

if your code work file then ok
In my case my app crash after these changes so I reslved app crash my changes these
MainApplication.java
 // Add imports
   import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.content.IntentFilter;
   import android.os.Build;
   import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;


   // ...
   // Put this above  "public void onCreate()":
  @Override
  public Intent registerReceiver(@Nullable BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 34 && getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion >= 34) {
      return super.registerReceiver(receiver, filter, Context.RECEIVER_EXPORTED);
    } else {
      return super.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }
  }
// ....

app/build.gradle
 dependencies {
     //  ...
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.2'
    // ...
}


First I have updated my targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion to 34
But my issue was not solved then i've updated my minSdkVersion to 34 and now the issue is resolved

As far as the targetsdkversion and compileSdkVersion concern, compileSdkVersion, targetsdkversion and minSdkVersion were deprecated. We have to replace them as shown below.
compileSdkVersion -> compileSdk,
minSdkVersion -> minSdk,
targetsdkversion -> targetSdk.

Redirect to app level build.gradle -> android/app/build.gradle
Please find attachment as well,

Happy Coding!

Google has changed its policy (to only 1-year-old Target API).
open your android/app/build.gradle
change:
targetSdkVersion 31

to:
targetSdkVersion 34


But i have already updated it and upload it this is my build.gradle
(http://gist.github.com/SambasBoyyyy/ee6e589508d38fe5e770bfbc66d5d84d)

Review All Tracks: Go to the Google Play Console and check all tracks (open testing, closed testing, and internal testing) for app.
Remove Old Versions: If any older versions targeting a lower API level are live, remove them.
Submit for Review: After making these changes, submit your app for review.

The warning tracks all the packages sent to the play console, you need to delete older versions or ignore if your latest version is already in conform with de API level required.
For example, my app is in the version 1.3.8, API level required, but the package from 1.0.17 (older) API level is not required.


If you are IONIC developer go to your projects folder then go to android folder then go variables.gradle file and edit the value
`ext {
   compileSdkVersion = 33
   targetSdkVersion = 33
   .....
}`

to
ext { compileSdkVersion = 34 targetSdkVersion = 34 ..... }


Using flutter I have the following in android/app/build.gradle
android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
...
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 33
        targetSdkVersion 34
...

In pubspec.yaml
  min_sdk_android: 33

It works on a lot of Android devices (e.g. Oppo A13 ColorOS, Samsung A71 A13, Samsung Galaxy Z A14),
but crashes on some (e.g. Pixel 8 A14).
From what I have seen it freezes on the start up launcher icon.
The latest release is the only active one in Google Play Console admin.
Maybe someone will shed some light on why it still crashes on some Android devices.

Finally I solved this problem! 
Follow my journey:
1st issue: This current one:
App must target Android 14 (API level 34) or higher is showing even after update to API level 34
Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78758690/21819819
2nd issue: Kotlin version
Task :react-native-screens:compileReleaseKotlin FAILED
Solution: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/issues/1369#issuecomment-1105152720
3rd issue:
Type mismatch: inferred type is Canvas? but Canvas was expected
Solution: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/issues/1787#issuecomment-1602198547
My scenario:
    "expo": "~46.0.19",
    "react-native": "0.69.6",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",


For me the issue was the new release was only rolled out to a percentage of the user base - in my case 20%.
This meant that the old release, targeting the old APK was still live.
Setting the release rollout to 100% changed the old release to 'superseded'.
